# cogroup IN PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark

The tutorial suggests this:

```
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("a", 2)])
>>> sorted(x.cogroup(y).collect())
[('a', ([1], [2])), ('b', ([4], []))]
```

However, on running this I get the following output:

```
('a', (<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1d8b190>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1d8b150>))
('b', (<pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1d8b210>, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x1d8b1d0>))
```

This has 3 level of nesting, if I store the output in 'r' and do this:

```
for i in r:
     for j in i[1]:
         print list(j)
```

I get the correct cogrouped numbers:

1) Why does Cogroup not return numbers like rightjoin/leftouterjoin etc. in PySpark?
2) Why can't I replicate the example on my PySpark shell?

Comment: Could you edit your post to link to the referenced tutorial?

Comment: @Nick: Here is the link, http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#cogroup , it might be that these tutorials are not valid for the latest release of Spark.

Comment: Yes, you're looking at the docs for 0.7.0. Spark's latest released version is now 1.0.0. The equivalent docs for `cogroup()` are [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#cogroup), and they appear to have the correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer, because that's what cogroup is supposed to return

```
  /**
   * For each key k in `this` or `other`, return a resulting RDD that contains a tuple with the
   * list of values for that key in `this` as well as `other`.
   */
  def cogroup[W](other: RDD[(K, W)]): RDD[(K, (Iterable[V], Iterable[W]))]
```

Joins in spark are actually implemented with cogroup, basically the join just breaks the iterables from cogroup into tuples. Here is the implantation of join from spark.

```
  def join[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], partitioner: Partitioner): RDD[(K, (V, W))] = {
    this.cogroup(other, partitioner).flatMapValues { case (vs, ws) =>
      for (v <- vs; w <- ws) yield (v, w)
    }
  }
```

As for the slight difference in interpreter output (keep in mind the output is the same except the pyspark Iterable doesn't show it's contents), I can't be sure unless I see the tutorial. The tutorial may be showing the output to be clearer even if that's not actually what appears. One more thing I ran a similar script in the scala shell, and it shows all the output.

```
Array((a,(ArrayBuffer(1),ArrayBuffer(2))), (b,(ArrayBuffer(4),ArrayBuffer())))
```